# RadEditor Validation message going only after postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik, radeditor

I have a RadEditor with a required field validator. The error message of required field validation disappers only after a post back. It is not disappearing after I enter any text in the radeditor.

I have tried to write a javascript for onblur event and hide the error message. But it is not working as expected in IE8. Once I enter any text, error message is disappearing but if I delete the text and make the radditor blank again, I am not getting the error message again. Thus it is not validating the required fields properly.

The javascript I have written for "onblur" event :

```
function DisableRequiredMessage(editor, args) {
var element = document.all ? editor.get_document().body : editor.get_document();
$telerik.addExternalHandler(element, "blur", function(e) {
var editor1 = $find("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContractExpirationAlertEditor");
var message1 = editor1.get_html();
if (message1 == '<br>' || message1 == '<p>&nbsp;</p>') 
document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_spnEmailBody').style.display = 'block';
else                               
document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_spnEmailBody').style.display = 'none';
});
}
```

I have also tried comparing length of the text and doin the same :

```
var editor2 = $find("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContractPendingEContractEditor");
var message2 = editor2.get_text();
if (message2.length > 1) 
document.getElementById('<%=spnContrPendngEmail.ClientID %>').style.display = 'none';

if (message2.length == 0 || message2.length == 1) 
document.getElementById('<%=spnContrPendngEmail.ClientID %>').style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: Where do call that `DisableRequiredMessage` function ?

Comment: In radeditor onclientload event. <telerik:RadEditor ID="ContractPendingReminderEContractEditor" runat="server" Skin="Gray"
                                        ToolsFile="~/Contracting/ToolsFile.xml" Width="100%" OnClientLoad="DisableRequiredMessage">

Answer (score 0):

You can attach to the [keydown event](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-attacheventhandler.html) or [OnClientSelectionChange](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-onclientselectionchange.html) event and check whether the content area is empty. If it is empty show the error message.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was helpful. I tried to use Keydown event and it worked.

Comment: The problem is even for keypress event, I have to get the content of radeditor.
If the content is null, I should display the required error message back.
When I am checking length of the text in radeditor after removing all the text, its showing length as 6/13(instead of 0) in IE.
And I tried to check the html text using get_html(). It showed presence of <br> or <p>&nbsp;</p> or <p><br></p>.
When I am trying to compare the text with this <br> etc. (as mentioned in the codes in last post), 
the loop is not getting executed at all in IE. But same is working fine in Mozilla.

Comment: Main Problem : "RequiredField error message" disappearing only after a post back. Not after we enter any text in teh rad editor. Solution I tried : In "onblur" or "Keypress" event, comparing the lenght of the text OR in the same events comparing the html text present. If html is like <br> or &nbsp;, then trying to hide the error message.But both Solution(comparing length and html text) Failed in IE and Moz.Sometimes its showing the html present in radeditor as <br> but still not hiding the error message.Please suggest some solution.